# Не получается записать Cookie

Tags: php, reactjs, yii2

Всем привет
У меня возникла проблема при записи cookie.
Есть 2 компьютера домашний и рабочий, на рабочем все работает исправно, но на домашнем нет.
Подскажите почему может быть следующая проблема с сохранением cookie или как понять почему она возникает. Записываю вот так
$cookies = \Yii::$app->response->cookies;

```
            $cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
                'name' => 'TEST',
                'value' => 'TEST',
            ]));
```

1. Скрин рабочий
2. Нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Какая ОС там и там?
2) Какой браузер используете там и там?
3) Какой веб-сервер там и там?

Comment: @delikates
Windows 10 и там и там
Браузер Opera 
Веб-сервер
Рабочий
Фронт Node js
Бэк Apache2.4
Не рабочий
Фронт Node js
Бэк OpenServer

Answer (score 0):

@delikates
Вот так выглядит ответ в браузере, где не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас браузер отклонил куку из-за cross-site. Либо выставьте в заголовках `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, либо укажите в пределах какого домена действует Ваша кука.

Comment: @delikates
Есть Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
htaccess приложен ниже
Также скриншот с параметрами запроса

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(localhost:3000|172.22.3.146:3000|192.168.0.68:3000)$" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "SameSite=None, Secure"
```

А вот скриншот с параметрами запроса[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С доменом не уверен, тк на двух пк одна версия проекта

Comment: Судя по скришотам у Вас Access-Control-Allow-Origin не *, а конкретный IP и даже c портом. Если я все верно помню, то в таком случае даже изменение номера порта может повлечь отклонение куки как cross-site

Comment: @delikates
Все верно, но мой ip и порт указаны в разрешенных 192.168.0.68:3000
Если убрать, то ответы для сервера не будут доступны

Comment: Тогда нужно уходить в отладку. Поставьте все же `*` проверьте как будет работать с ним. Попробуйте указать в опциях `Yii\web\cookie` параметры `domain`, `path`, `expire` посмотрите как будет работать с ними. Попробуйте на `нерабочей` поднять вместо `openServer` ту же версию `Apache`, что и на рабочей - фиг знает, что `openserver` накидал в ее конфиги в своей сборке.